# I need to verify the power law in this question

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]
Question.

[image]
I suppose the value of Vx must be positive. So how do I manipulate the equation such that Vx becomes positive?

[image]
Can this be the solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement that Vx must be positive. After you analyze a circuit you may find that any given voltage is positive or negative, and any given current is positive or negative.

What is required is that when calculating power with \$P = VI\$ you must follow the passive sign convention. If you do that, then the power calculated for any resistor **must** be positive...resistors always consume power. Also, power **must** be conserved in a dc circuit, so the calculated power values for all elements must sum to zero.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I was trying to calculate only the power absorbed by the two resistors. So, since the power of the 25ohms resistor is positive, then Vx must also be positive to make sure that power absorbed by the 15ohms resistor is positive.

Comment: No, that is not true. The voltage can be negative across a resistor and it's power will still be positive. You **must** consider also the direction and value of the current, and mind the passive sign convention.

Comment: Oh okay. The solution that I just posted, is this the correct solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't give out homework solutions. You can, and should, check it yourself. Is power conserved? Is the power for all resistors positive? Is KCL satisfied at every node? Is KVL satisfied for every loop?

Comment: Alright. I'll check that. Thank you.